# Why doesn't a parent element with a background cover a child element with a width larger than the viewport?

Tags: html, css

Take [this simple HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/nbotqr3z/):

```css
#parent {
  background: pink;
}

#child {
  width: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">Hello</div>
</div>
```

The `#parent` element's pink background doesn't persist across the entire `#child` element. Why is this?

Setting the background on the `body` element [does](https://jsfiddle.net/nbotqr3z/1/) apply to the entire `#child`, even though the `#parent` and `body` share the same width, i.e. the viewport width.

Curiously, setting the `#parent` element's display to `inline-block` [fixes](https://jsfiddle.net/nbotqr3z/2/) this issue, though I have no idea why!

Any help here would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The `#parent`'s pink background doesn't persist across the entire `#child`. Why is this?

It's because a block-level element has a default width of `100%`. In this case, it has a width of `100%` of the `body` element, which is the same as the viewport.

In other words, even though the element's child has a width of `5000px`, it will still have a width of `100%` of whatever the viewport is, which means that the background will not extend to cover the child element. The reason this doesn't apply to the `body` element is because the `body` element is a special case, and [the values are treated as if they were specified on the root element](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#body-background). See:

> [**3.11.2. The Canvas Background and the HTML `<body>` Element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#body-background)
>
> The used values of that `body` element's background properties are their initial values, and the propagated values are treated as if they were specified on the root element.

> Curiously, setting the `#parent` display to `inline-block` fixes this issue, though I have no idea why!

That's because it is no longer a block-level element with a width of `100%`. Also, `inline-block` elements have a ["shrink-to-fit" width](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#lsquo), which means that they will take the width of the child element. Similarly adding `display: table` would have similar results.

Comment: +1. There are so many answers on Stack Overflow that tell you to use `display: inline-block`, but this is a rare one I've stumbled on that actually tells why.

Comment: Thanks @Josh! Is there any way to get this behavior, while still keeping it a block-level element? Alternatively, are there any pitfalls to be aware of to rely on inline-block to solve this issue?

Also: How come the `body` element, which has the viewport width, doesn't suffer from this?

Comment: I too mostly get into serious trouble over inherit values .. That don't work as I expect..

Comment: @Mendel I updated the answer to explain why this doesn't happen with the `body` element. The closest behavior would probably be to use `display: table`, although I don't think there are any pitfalls when using `inline-block`, that should work in most cases.